# Avoid creating new azure key vault secret version if one already exists in C#

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault, azure-secrets

I am writing my own Azure KeyVault wrapper in C#, and I would like to have a functionality that allows me to specify what should happen if I attempt to upload a secret using a name that already exists:

```
public enum ActionIfExists
{
  Fail,
  Rename,
  Overwrite
}
```

But when I was trying to implement this, I couldn't see how one would actually check if a secret exists using the methods of the [SecretClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient). Neither have I found a setting in the [SecretClientOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclientoptions) or method parameters for [SetSecretAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.setsecretasync) to tell it to "fail upon collisions", or something that would prevent silent overwrites.

I have now implemented this "exists" by downloading the secret, and returning `true` if it succeeds or `false` when an error occurs. But I'd rather have a function like [BlobContainerClient.ExistsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.existsasync) than needlessly downloading sensitive data "as a test".

Has anyone ever done this or an idea why it isn't possible?

Comment: You could call _.GetPropertiesOfSecretVersions(string)_. It returns a _Pageable<>_. If it doesn't fail, the secret exists.